# How do I create a list from a data frame, containing each value of string column, multiplied by a second column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

The question gets much clearer when an example is provided.
I have a Data Frame with two columns, one of type string and one of type integer:

```
Col1   Col2
-------------
str1    2
str2    4
str3    1
```

now i need a list that contains the string in Col1 times the number in Col2, i.e. `['str1', 'str1', 'str2', 'str2', 'str2', 'str2', 'str3']`.

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: `np.repeat(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])`.

Comment: wow, that was quick. thats it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(df.Col1.values, df.Col2.values)
```

Output:

```
array(['str1', 'str1', 'str2', 'str2', 'str2', 'str2', 'str3'])
```